# Lazy load an Octree from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, octree

I work on a 3D map renderer for iOS and Android using which is mainly written in C++. I use an Octree to load and store data from a file.

So far all is fine, rendering small to medium maps of some square km is all cool and all works fluid. But now I want to increase the size of the maps, like whole country or continent size.

There are plenty Octree implementations and tutorials - but so far I have not found a single tutorial explaining how to efficiently handle lazy loading and tree construction for large data sets.

Optimally there exists a free available Octree library which already does that. Do you know such? Otherwise, what must be done to implement lazy loading into an Octree in general?

Comment: Did you even try a search for "octree library"?  Tops in the result, for example: http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__octree.html

Comment: ... I was not asking for help to use Google. Yes, I also know the PCL implementation. And no, it doesn't offer lazy loading. Or I missed something badly.

Comment: In case it isn't clear: By lazy loading I mean to lazily initialize Octree nodes and associated data efficiently from disk as they become relevant (in visible bounds). I'm not talking about loading an Octree in a background thread.